# Bash: stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device when SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, stty

I'm writing and simple bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "IP: $1"
sshpass -p 'pass' ssh -t -q -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$1 << EOF
    cd ../
    sed -i -e 's/x=false/x=true/g' file.txt
    echo "*** x has changed! ***"
    cat file.txt
EOF
```

I run the script like this:

bash test.sh ip (I enter some server IP).

The script works but I get this message in the terminal:

```
IP: ip
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
*** x has changed! ***
x = true
```

Why does the stty message appear? what does it mean and how can I make it disappear?
(I try some suggestions that I found on web, but nothing helped).

Thanks!

Comment: Does the remote host have a login script or similar which runs `stty`?

Comment: Actually, I don't know. Is there a way to check it?

Comment: If you are able to log in over SSH, definitely. Without more information about which OS or shell the remote system runs, there isn't much more we can tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Add `bash` to avoid loading initialization files :

```
sshpass -p 'pass' ssh -T -q -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$1 bash << EOF
```

You don't seem to need `-t`, so use `-T`